# Ошибка "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1" с пустым json файлом в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json
filename = 'numbers.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        answ = json.load(f_obj)
except FileNotFoundError:
    answ = input('Enter number: ')
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(answ, f_obj)
        print('Answer saved!')
else:
    print(answ)
```

Вот данные трассировки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numbers.py", line 7, in <module>
    answ = json.load(f_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Очевидно, в файле не json

Comment: Здесь бы поподробнее, не вижу где ошибка.

Comment: Мы тоже не видим, вы ведь содержимое файла не показали

Comment: Файл просто пустой, numbers.json не содержит ничего

Comment: Пустота это ведь не json, так что ничего удивительного, что пустоту не получается прочитать

Answer (score 2):

Вы написали, что ваш файл - пустой. Не могу формально это обосновать, но смею считать, что пустая строка не представляет из себя корректный JSON-документ.
Попробовал в консоли браузера:

`JSON.parse(2) // Полёт нормальный`

`JSON.parse("") // Syntax Error`

Попробуйте добавить в ваш код проверку на пустоту файла

Answer (score 0):

Тут 2 варианта:
1. Ошибка декодирования. Возможно файл не в utf-8
2. Попытка декодировать множественный json. В таком случае, стоит использовать конструкцию вида `json.loads('{}')`

Comment: 1й вариант однозначно отпадает, я проверил - utf-8. изменил на json.loads - получил вот это:        Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "numbers.py", line 7, in <module>
    answ = json.loads(f_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper